# Not pushing correct regex match to JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex

**Overview:**

I'm using regex to parse a text document and create a JSON document. The document is parsed from console logs.

What seems to happen is `(regex_1_match && regex_2_match)` is not working as expected. It seems to be matching `regex_1` and looks to fulfill `regex_2` and saving it int the same array.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const filename = fs.readFileSync('test.txt').toString();
var regex_1 = /"Course([0-9.])"/g;
var regex_2 = /"(Name)"/g;
var regex_3 = /"(No Name)"/g;
var regex_1_match = filename.match(regex_1);
var regex_2_match = filename.match(regex_2);
var regex_3_match = filename.match(regex_3);

let testJSON = [];

//for each line item
for  (let index = 0; index < filename.length; index++) {
  if(regex_1_match && regex_2_match) {
    testJSON.push({
      Course: regex_1[index]
      Name: regex_2[index]
    });
  }
}
fs.writeFileSync("parsed_test_doc",JSON.stringify(testJSON));
```

**test.txt:**

```
------------ Course1 ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ Name ------------
------------ Course2 ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ No Name ------------
------------ Course3 ------------
------------ Name ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ Course4 ------------
------------ No Name ------------
------------ Course5 ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ Name ------------
```

**Output:**

```
[{
  "Course": "Course1",
  "Name": "Name"
}, {"Course": "Course2",
  "Name": "Name"
},{"Course": "Course3",
  "Name": "Name"
},{"Course": "Course4",
},{{"Course": "Course5"
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```js
[{
  "Course": "Course1",
  "Name": "Name"
}, {
  "Course": "Course2"
}, {
  "Course": "Course3",
  "Name": "Name"
}, {
  "Course": "Course4"
}, {
  "Course": "Course5",
  "Name": "Name"
}]
```

Comment: Are you sure your `for` loop is correct? Iterating over a string iterates each character, not line

Comment: Also, there's no way `JSON.stringify()` produced your _"output"_ since it's not valid JSON

Comment: Why do your regular expressions contains `"` characters? They don't appear in your text example

Comment: Sorry I did not validate my test example I will validate. Its a very simplified version of what I am currently working with, and you're right the `"` character should be removed. I do not have this in my dev build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes about the example code

- In the current code and the example text, this part `regex_1_match && regex_2_match` is true if the result from [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) (which is either an array or null) is true for both matches, which can give you unexpected results
- Note that the variable `filename` contains the whole file, so `index` in this loop will be the number of each character in the file content
- Using index to index into the regex `regex_1[index]` does not work this way, perhaps you meant to index into the match
- `regex_3_match` is never used

What you might do is use a single pattern with 2 capture groups, where group 2 captures the first occurrence of Name and it is optional.

```
\b(Course\d+)(?:(?!Course\d)[^])*?(?:No Name|(Name)|(?=Course\d))
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(Course\d+)` Capture in **group 1** `Course` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!Course\d)[^]` Match any char if `Course` and 1+ digits not directly to the right
- `)*?` Close non capture group and optionally repeat it non greedy
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `No Name|(Name)|(?=Course\d)` Match `No Name`, or capture `Name` in **group 2** or assert the next `Course` and a digit to continue the match when there is no Name present.
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIxfvm/1)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filename = fs.readFileSync('test.txt').toString();
const regex = /\b(Course\d+)(?:(?!Course\d)[^])*?(?:No Name|(Name)|(?=Course\d))/g;
const result = Array.from(filename.matchAll(regex), m => {
    let res = {"Course": m[1]}
    if (undefined !== m[2]) {
        console.log("not undefined")
        res["Name"]=m[2];
    }
    return res;
});
console.log(result);
```

Output

```
[
  { Course: 'Course1', Name: 'Name' },
  { Course: 'Course2' },
  { Course: 'Course3', Name: 'Name' },
  { Course: 'Course4' },
  { Course: 'Course5', Name: 'Name' }
]
```

```js
const s = `------------ Course1 ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ Name ------------
------------ Course2 ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ No Name ------------
------------ Course3 ------------
------------ Name ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ Course4 ------------
------------ No Name ------------
------------ Course5 ------------
------------ foo ------------
------------ Name ------------`;
const regex = /\b(Course\d+)(?:(?!Course\d)[^])*?(?:No Name|(Name)|(?=Course\d))/g;
const result = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => {
  let res = {
    "Course": m[1]
  }
  if (undefined !== m[2]) {
    res["Name"] = m[2];
  }
  return res;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think they meant to iterate and index into the match results, not the regexp.